# Spring Security + Spring MVC interceptor - mapping to the same pattern conflict?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, interceptor

I'm facing the following problem (although I'm not quite sure if it is a problem or not...):

I have implemented a 3-step user registration wizard using Spring MVC.
Upon 3rd step success, new `UserDetails` object is created and placed in the security context,  as in:

```
...
UserDetails newUser = new PanelUser(customer, AuthenticationService.getFixedAuthorities());
    Authentication authentication = 
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(newUser, null, newUser.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

because new user should be treated as authenticated (i.e. logged on). The intercept URL pattern is defined as follows:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/account/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Now, here is "the problem".
While the user is successfully registered, there may be a long operation still running in the background, triggered by the registration process. And until this operation is not finished (essentially it just sets a specific bool flag in the `user` table upon completion), the user, even though logged in, should not be able to see any page with the very same URL pattern, i.e. `/account/**`, but instead should be redirected (I guess) to the info page, telling him that account access is pending while this background operation completes.

What I tried is the following:
I defined MVC interceptor, implementing `HandlerInterceptor` and did the following in the `preHandle` method

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
                 Object arg2) throws Exception {
    // omitted for brevity...
    // explicitly load from DB
    Customer customer = this.customerService.getUserByUsername(pUser.getUsername());
    if(customer.getStatus() == CustomerStatus.Suspended.getCode()) {
        //arg1.sendRedirect("../pending");
        // it should actually return appropriate info view, 
        // or redirect, this is just for test...
        arg1.getOutputStream().write("Account access pending".getBytes());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the config

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/account/**"/>
    <bean id="accountAccessInterceptor"
          class="rs.slb.customerpanel.utils.AccountAccess">
        <property name="customerService" ref="customerService" />
    </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

With this, I faced a bit of a strange behaviour, that kinda resembles a race condition (in my opinion) between Spring Security interceptor, and Spring MVC interceptor on the same URL pattern (sometimes the response is returned first, sometimes the login form).

**EDIT**
The strange behaviour was actually presenting itself when I actually tried to do the redirect, instead of straight write back some response. Now I cannot seem to reproduce it...

Can someone advise something here, how should I properly go about this?

Comment: Quick question: is your application using Spring Security filters (as defined at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) somewhere else? Is it possible to have your mvc interceptor converted to a Security filter?

Comment: Well no, I haven't configured any custom security filters, if that's what you're asking. It came to mind that I could maybe do something purely with Spring security, but could you be more specific ?

Comment: I've removed my previous answer for the sake of correctness. I do not have a large experience with SS filters, but I'll post something else if I find something related to your question.